# Missing Renew Now button for Apple Developer program

Tags: ios, macos, iphone-developer-program

I'm on auto-renew for the Apple Developer program.  My renewal date is 3 weeks away.  iTunes Connect keeps warning me that my membership is going to expire.  Growing tired of the unnecessary warning, I tried to renew early.  According to the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/:

> You can renew starting 30 days before the expiration date of your existing membership or any time after it expires. Your expiration date is available in your account on the developer website. To renew, sign in to your account with the Apple ID you used to enroll, and click the "Renew Now” button.

I cannot find a Renew Now button anywhere on https://developer.apple.com/.  I know in the member center had the button in past years. I'm a little hesitant to turn off auto-renew this close to my expiration date.

- I'm logged into the correct Apple ID.
- I tried using Safari and Chrome.

Anyone know where the Renew Now button is?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem though the automatic renewal option is present now.

Comment: On your iPhone or iPad, go to Settings -> Apple ID -> Subscriptions. You should be able to renew from there.

I was having the same issue because the instructions on the Apple Developer site say that the renew button is in the Apple Developer app, but it is not there.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

The button was hidden!

Go through the HTML. Look for autorenew in the DOM until you find a  tag and remove it's display:none.

Never had to fight this hard to give someone money!
Love you apple!

Comment: Unbelievably, this was the case and un-hiding the button solved it! To be precise, the class `.ng-hide` was applied to the renew button and was preventing it (and several other buttons) from showing.

Comment: @PatrickBassut I tried this , i was able to unhide the button but after clicking on "Renew Membership" nothing happens and in the network tab if i see the response it says "Renewal not allowed on this team" any idea how do go about it?

Answer (score 2):

**"Renew Membership" button will be present for the users whose auto-renew feature is turned off.**
[image]

If auto-renew is turned on then no need to worry.

Comment: On my account (and presumably the OP or the question would not have been asked) a notice much like that shows up, but *without* the 'Renew Membership' button, only 'Enable Auto-Renew'.

Answer (score 2):

For me I had to

1. Use **Safari** to Open https://developer.apple.com/
2. Navigate to Account > Membership
3. Scroll all the way down, disable Auto-Renew Membership via un-ticking the green tick
4. Hard Reload Page - **HOLD DOWN SHIFT AND CLICK REFRESH**

If that does not work
1. Log Out on Safari
2. Log In on a different browser (Chrome / Firefox) - then Log Out
3. Log In Safari
4. Hard Reload Page - **HOLD DOWN SHIFT AND CLICK REFRESH**

Comment: Yes, shift-refreshing did it for me.

Comment: @Dieskim I am not able to see this check-Box.

Comment: I have found that logging out and logging in a new incognito browser tab also helps sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the Auto-Renew Membership option is ticked, but the **entire section is disabled** (because the membership has just expired).
Just like the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

In order to show the Renew Now button, we need to turn the option off, but we cannot untick the option directly as it is greyed out.

What we have to do is:

1. Right-click on the Auto-Renew Membership option and click `Inspect`
2. Find out the `<li class="setting checkbox-setting row disabled table-row selected" >` element in the inspector
   [image: screenshot of the inspector]
3. Remove the `disabled` class and the option is now clickable
4. Untick the Auto-Renew Membership option
5. Try to refresh the page a few times, now we can see the alert and the Renew Now button

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this in the future:

I just got off the phone with Apple Developer Support. What's supposed to happen is

a) If you have auto-renew turned on, it just automatically renews like planned

b) If you have auto-renew turned off, a banner like the one in the accepted answer is supposed to show up to prompt you to turn on auto-renew or to renew manually (if it's within 30 days of it needing to be renewed)

What a lot of us are running into is: that banner is not showing up.

As I was using Safari on a Mac to do this, Apple Developer Support told me to clear Safari history (History -> Clear History...) and caches (Develop menu (may need to enable in Preferences) -> Empty Caches) then close/exit Safari and open and log in and try again.

I really figured this would not fix the issue - but it did. Now the banner showed up and I could renew manually. And then turn auto-renew back on.

So, if anyone has tried everything, try that.

Comment: Is this worked for any one?

Answer (score 0):

Download **Apple Developer** app in iphone, ipad, or mac-> Go to Accounts -> Login (if not already login) -> there you will find renew button.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Open the `Apple Developer` app on your Mac and go to the account section. There click on the `View` button and you'll find the renew button

[image]

[image]

Comment: there is no renew button visible? how to renew.

Comment: I already renewed in this screenshot so it is not visible but the button should be there if the membership is about to expire soon

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue

Comment: found any solution?